# What are the uses of Packet Tracer Software in Web Development?

Tags: routes, frontend, packet, cisco, web-development-server

I am little new to programming and web development. I have some experience in CISCO Packet Tracer software and I have no idea how could it be used in web development. I know it is for routing and networking applications. But I have a feeling that it might be used as a valuable tool for web development. Specially front-end development.

Answer (score -1):

The only scenario I can image would be configuring a web server in cisco packet tracer.
But I don't think that this is the kind of usage you're thinking about or is it?
[Web Server in Cisco Packet Tracer](https://gwaxprograms.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-set-web-server-in-cisco-packet.html)